# Send SMS for Missed Calls only once Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, phone-call

i want to send a sms once. if already sent i want to skip the code or somthing.

```
             Log.i("Send SMS", "");
             String phoneNo = incomingNumber;
             String newN = incomingNumber;
              if (newN!=oldN)
                {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    String message = "im on a meeting call you later -ExAutoSmS-";
                try {
                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                 oldN = incomingNumber;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

@ RAJITHA first create [shared preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) then check every time before sending an sms if there is no number exist in shared preference..

But remember shared preference store number till you didn't clear or delete the app.. so after finish your task clear the saved no from preferences..

Hope you helped..[enter link description here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/04/sharedpreferences-in-android.html)